# android google maps crash on Nexus S

Tags: android, maps, nexus-s

I am developing an app which makes use of Google Maps. It runs fine on all devices except for a specific device: Google Nexus S - we have access to only one such device.
The error is that when navigating in Maps, the application crashes with an OutOfMemoryError.
Below is the stack trace:

```
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.createSnapshot(ZoomHelper.java:444)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.beginZoom(ZoomHelper.java:194)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$2.onScaleBegin(MapView.java:380)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ScaleGestureDetector.java:261)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:682)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1714)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-18 14:17:52.601 E/AndroidRuntime( 2714):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody confirm if they ran into the same issue? If so, do you happen to have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is running out of memory. Are you using a lot of memory other places in your app (i.e. loading large bitmaps)?

Comment: I am using and loading bitmaps ... some of them are large indeed, but they are not loaded in map activity. Do you happen to have any resources/links on how to make bitmap loading more efficiently without losing quality?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on my Galaxy S2 with ICS 4.0.4. I cleared the data from apps menu for Google map and force stopped it. Restarted Google Map after this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same thing w/ my TF201.

Uninstall all the updates and then reinstall it **via desktop market. (play.google.com)** .
At least that worked for me.
Probably delete cached data and all that stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this question, here's the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) from Android developers on how to work with bitmaps efficiently.